# Is my application of Cauchy-Riemann right?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, self-learning

**Question:**
Given $f(z) =  3z^2 + 9z^3 -z$.
1. Find $f^\prime(z)$
2. Find $f(z)$ when $z = 3 + 2i$
3. Use Cauchy-Riemann to find if $f(z)$ is differentiable at $3 + 2i$

---

**My Attepmt:**
1. $f^\prime(z) = 6z + 27z^2 - 1$
2. 
$$
\begin{align}
f(3 + 2i)
&= 3(3+2i)^2 + 9(3+2i)^3 - (3 + 2i)\\
&= 3(9-4+6i)+9(9-8i+54i-36) - (3+2i)\\
&= (15 + 18i) + (81 - 72i + 486i - 324) -(3 + 2i)\\
&= -231 + 430i\\
\end{align}
$$
3. For this, I substituted $z = x + iy$ in $f(z)$, then expanded the brackets. After that, I grouped the like terms together and expressed $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$. I got this as a result of my calculations:
$$
\begin{align}
u(x,y) &= 3x^2 - 3y^2 + 9x^3 -9y^3 - 27xy^2\\
v(x,y) &= 6xiy + 2x^2iy - iy
\end{align}
$$
Then, I calculated partial derivatives $u_x, v_y, u_y$ and $v_x$. For Cauchy-Riemann, $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$. I substituted x = 3 and y = 2 in the partial derivative and found that it **fails** C.R. equations. Hence, **NO, IT IS NOT DIFERENTIABLE AT $3 + 2i$**

---

**Can someone please verify this for me ?**

Comment: You forgot a term in your expression for $u$. You're missing $-x$.

Comment: A small remark: $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, so you should remove the "i" from your definition of $v(x,y)$. If I am not wrong the C.R. equations fail because $6x+27x^2-27z^2=u_x$ while $v_y=6x+2x^2-1$. No need to select special $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Avitus According to Cameron , $u(x,y)$ is wrong. I am calculating again.

Comment: @LittleChild, also the $-9y^3$ term belongs with $v$, not $u$. Your $v$ is also very incorrect. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%28x%2Biy%29%5E2%2B9%28x%2Biy%29%5E3-%28x%2Biy%29) and scroll to the part where it says "assuming $x$ and $y$ are real".

Comment: @CameronWilliams I was told that all terms with $i$ go to $iv(x,y)$

Comment: Yes,but the $i$ doesn't go into the $v$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Recalculating .. please wait :)

Comment: @LittleChild let me work a simpler example for you. Suppose $g(z) = z^2 + z + 1$ and we want to break it into its $u$ and $v$ components. $g(x,y) = g(x+iy) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Working with our definition $z = x+iy$ we have that $g(x,y) = (x+iy)^2 + (x+iy) + 1 = (x^2 + 2ixy - y^2) + (x+iy) + 1$. Let's collect the purely real and purely imaginary parts separately. We get $g(x,y) = (x^2-y^2+x+1) + i(2xy+y)$. So this says that $u(x,y) = x^2-y^2+x+1$ and $v(x,y) = 2xy+y$. Try showing that this function is holomorphic (analytic) by using the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: I have tried to improve the mark-up and LaTeX in your question. While it is possible to use HTML in posts, it often creates distracting formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong.  This is a polynomial, so it is differentiable, and the C-R equations should be true.

EDIT: In this case I get
$$\eqalign{ u &= 9\,{x}^{3}-27\,x{y}^{2}+3\,{x}^{2}-3\,{y}^{2}-x,
\cr  v &= 27\,{x}^{2}y-9\,{y}^{
3}+6\,xy-y\cr
u_x &= 27 x^2 - 27 y^2 + 6 x - 1 = v_y\cr
u_y &= -54 x y - 6 y = - v_x}$$

Comment: What about 1st and 2nd ?

Comment: More importantly: it is a polynomial in $z$. A function $f$ is complex differentiable at a point if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}} = 0$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I am new to this. How do I differentiate with respect to $z bar$ ??

Comment: @LittleChild, it's useful to know but a lot of the time it's not introduced in a first course in complex analysis. But effectively saying that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}} = 0$ is the same as saying that $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations. But to answer your question: $\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ah ok ! Can you gimme a problem to solve where $f(z)$ is not a polynomial ?? I will try to find $f\prime(z)$

Comment: @LittleChild try to prove/disprove differentiability of $f(z)=\bar{z}$. This is a very interesting one.

Comment: @Avitus How do I know which term goes to $u(x,y)$ and which to $iv(x,y)$

Comment: @LittleChild, since $f(z) = f(x+iy) = f(x,y)$, we have that $f(x,y) = \overline{x+iy} = x-iy$. Since we want to write $f(x,y)$ as $u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, we need that $u(x,y) = x$ and $v(x,y) = -y$ (equate the real and imaginary parts separately).

Comment: @CameronWilliams and my first 2 answers are right ??

Comment: @LittleChild the first definitely is and I think the second is as well.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: you only needed to show it differentiable at $3+2i$ ;-)